# How to map a block to an Enumerable in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, enumerable

Here's what I'm trying

```
class Lorem

  def ipsum &block
    data = get_data
    data.each { |id| block.call dolor(id) } if block_given?
    data
  end

  def dolor id
    {dolor: id}
  end

  private

  def get_data
    [1, 2, 3] # some fake data
  end

end

stuff = []
panda = Lorem.new
panda.ipsum { |thing| stuff << thing }

puts stuff.inspect
# => [{dolor: 1}, {dolor: 2}, {dolor: 3}]
```

### Code smell!

This block feels really gross. Specifically the line with `block_given?`. Is there a better way to write it?

```
def ipsum &block
  data = get_data
  data.each { |id| block.call dolor(id) } if block_given?
  data
end
```

Can i somehow use `&method` or some other magics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify slightly:

```
def ipsum
  data = get_data
  data.each { |id| yield dolor(id) } if block_given?
  data
end
```

Taking advantage of the fact that `Array#each` returns the array, this is arguably even simpler, but I'm not sure I like it:

```
def ipsum
  return get_data unless block_given?
  get_data.each { |id| yield dolor(id) }
end
```

Comment: @naomik You're welcome! And thanks for the edit -- I love `unless`, and I always forget to use it.